# How do I determine how long a HTTP request took to upload on Tornado / Flask / Python?

Tags: python, flask, tornado, wsgi

***Note: this may not be doable without `Flask`/`WSGI`/`Tornado` modification (which is unacceptable).*** Please see the "why not just modify the code?" section below.

I need to have my `Flask`/`WSGI`/`Tornado` server determine how long it took for an HTTP client to upload its data on a big `POST`/`PUT`. All the `Flask`/`Tornado` callbacks I see are only called once the entire `Content-Length` has been uploaded.

I need this information so that I can better service slow requests and/or prioritize swiftly-uploaded requests over the slower ones, etc.

However, I just don't see any callbacks available for this in either `Flask`,`Werkzeug` or `Tornado`, nor members on the `Flask.request` object to obtain this information.

**Regarding the answer given by [lord63-j](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/users/4890577/lord63-j)**: *while really cool*, it is not what is needed. By the time an `app.route()` handler is called, the entire `POST`/`PUT` data has already been uploaded.

### Why not just modify the code?

Spelunking shows that the best place to modify code is in `HTTP1Connection.start_serving`, to add in a `start time` that `WSGI`/`Flask` can then use. *SADLY*, the delegate's `data_received` future only takes body data as an argument, meaning this `start time` data will be lost when passed on.

Alternatively, `Tornado`'s `_RequestDispatcher.headers_received` (start) and `execute` (complete) functions can be modified to store the current time at each stage, but you would still have the problem of passing the time to `WSGI`/`Flask`. *(`headers_received` is acceptable as headers will typically be much smaller than the body)*

As you can see, this quickly becomes a rabbit hole.

Comment: found this might help you .. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/#upload-progress-bars

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately, I don't think it gets me any farther: by the time Flask and Werkzeug and Tornado do the unpronounceable dance, the data has already been uploaded...and that appears to be reflected in the link. However, it did have some other things I am interested in. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a good idea, but you could try [`after_this_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.after_this_request).

A simple example:

```
import time

from flask import Flask, after_this_request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    before = time.time()
    @after_this_request
    def cal_time(response):
        print(time.time() - before)
        return response
    return 'Hello, world.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

then you should see the time printed in the console.

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
0.000116109848022
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2015 20:41:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

You you can have a try and see if it works for you. I tried the upload example in the flask doc and seem work fine.